# Fisher Information for parametrized Binomial

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, fisher-information

I am  trying to calculate the Fisher Information for a $Bin(n,p)$ with the following parametrization:

$$\theta=\text{log}\frac{p}{1-p}$$ 
which implies: 
$$p=\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta}$$

I tried two methods but got two different answers:

$$f_\theta(x)={n\choose k}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$$

In canonical form:

$$f_\theta(x)=e^{log{n\choose  k}+x\theta+nlog(\frac{1}{1+e^\theta})}$$

then the fisher information is 
$$\frac{d^{2}(-n*log\frac{1}{1+e^\theta})}{d\theta^2}=\frac{-ne^\theta}{(1+e^\theta)^2}$$

When I calculate it directly(not using canonical form i.e taking the second derivative and taking the negative expected value) I get:

$$log f_\theta(x)=log {n\choose x}+x*log(\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta})+(n-x)log(\frac{1}{1+e^\theta})$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}log f_\theta(x)=\frac{x(1-e^\theta)}{e^\theta}-(n-x)(1-e^\theta)$$

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}log f_\theta(x)=(n-x)e^\theta -\frac{x}{e^\theta}$$

$$E[-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}log f_\theta(x)]=\frac{n(1-e^\theta)}{1+e^\theta}$$
Which one is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by calculation directly? The first one is correct

Comment: Taking the second derivative and taking the negative expected value

Comment: The second derivative with respect to what?

Comment: I am taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$

Comment: There cannot be any difference since you do the same twice. You can add to the question the mentioned direct calculations  in order that we can find error.

Comment: I have include the second work

Comment: The derivatives looks wrong. Say, the $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(x\log(\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta})\right) = x\frac{1}{(1+e^\theta)^2}. 
$$

Comment: Sorry, extra 2 in power. It should be $x\cdot \frac{1}{1+e^\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. So
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(x\log(\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta})\right) 
= x \frac{1+e^\theta}{e^\theta}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta} \right) = 
 x \frac{1+e^\theta}{e^\theta}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+e^\theta} \right) $$
$$
= x \frac{1+e^\theta}{e^\theta}\cdot \frac{1}{(1+e^\theta)^2} \cdot e^\theta = 
x\frac{1}{1+e^\theta}.
$$
And the second derivative is 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(x\frac{1}{1+e^\theta}\right) =- x \frac{1}{(1+e^\theta)^2} \cdot e^\theta.
$$

Comment: you are correct I made a mistake and kept the derivation. I get the same answer now. Math is not broken!. Thank you